# printing array in c passed from java : Why doesn't the array get printed?

Tags: java, c, arrays, java-native-interface

The following *java* snippet calls a *c* function :

*Java Code*

```
 String s[] = new String[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        s[i] = "s";
    }
    o.printArrayLength(s); // prints the array length from c code
```

*C Code :*

```
void Java_Package_CallMethodOfSuperClass_printArrayLength
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray arr) {

jsize size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,arr);
printf("\n");
printf("Size of array from C : ");
printf("%d",size);
jcharArray chrArr = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env,arr,NULL);
char Arr[11];
strcpy(Arr,chrArr);
int i = 0;
printf("Now printing the array declared in java from c :");
printf("SIZE SIZE SIZE SIZE : %d",size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
    printf("Inside for loop !");
    printf("%s",Arr[i]);
}
     //jobjectArray obArr = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,size,(*env)->FindClass(env,"[L"),NULL);
    //(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,obArr,0,chrArr);
}
```

When the above happens i see the following output :

```
Size of array from C : 10
Now printing the array declared in java from c :
SIZE SIZE SIZE SIZE : -549339085 // What the heck !
```

Why do i get the value of size different from 10. Value 10 is printed 1 line before.

Next if i keep the check in the for loop to 10 then also the array doesn't get printed. Why is this ? Instead i get a fatal error .

Answer (score 5):

You should observe your compiler warnings, of which there should be several. This code is broken.

You are declaring an array of 11 characters (`Arr`), but treating it as an array of 10 strings. Strings in C  are represented as pointers to `char`. Your `strcpy()` is very likely overriting `Arr`, which is causing the value of `size` to change.

Comment: I am unable to do. Can you please help